# Using Global variables in Google app engine python webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, global-variables

> Is it right to use global variables in Google app engine?

I used them in one of my app and it turns out they tends to get flushed after small period of time when app is not being used.

If i am right is there a alternative?

Comment: @JoeBenet can you please explain why the python tag has been added.

Comment: @thecoshman I guess because it's in the title as well.. so it is for Python :)

Comment: ¬_¬ I feel so stupid right now...

Comment: @thecoshman No worries.. I read it twice before checking the title ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use webapp2 you can use a registry. http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#registry
And there is a request registry: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#registry